# Early stopping with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, recommendation-engine

I am doing multi-class classification for a recommender system (item recommendations), and I'm currently training my network using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss. Therefore, it is reasonable to perform `EarlyStopping` by monitoring my validation loss, `val_loss` as such:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)
```

which works as expected. However, the performance of the network (recommender system) is measured by Average-Precision-at-10, and is tracked as a metric during training, as `average_precision_at_k10`. Because of this, I could also perform early stopping with this metric as such:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='average_precision_at_k10', patience=10)
```

which also works as expected.

**My problem:**
Sometimes the validation loss increases, whilst the Average-Precision-at-10 is improving and vice-versa. Because of this, I would need to monitor **both**, and perform early stopping, **if and only if** both are deteriorating. What I would like to do:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor=['val_loss', 'average_precision_at_k10'], patience=10)
```

which obviously does not work. Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: The simple solution/question right away. Did you try creating a third function like 'avg_prc_at_10k_and_val_loss' and do the early stopping inside this method? Like "if val_loss() is decreasing AND avg_precision_at_k10 is decresing -> early_stop = true"...

Comment: I thought about it, but did not find sufficient documentation. I understand a custom EarlyStopping function can be created, as described here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26833/is-there-away-to-change-the-metric-used-by-the-early-stopping-callback-in-keras . It extends the model class, therefore `self.model.stop_training` can be set, but I am unaware how to access the value of the current metrics, eg. `val_loss` in a similar fashion. Do you have any idea?

Comment: the custom callback framework in my answer shows how to access these metrics. Given that framework you should be able to develop the code you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With guidance from [Gerry P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559644/11764097) above I managed to create my own custom EarlyStopping callback, and thought I post it here in case anyone else are looking to implement something similar.

If **both** the *validation loss* **and** the *mean average precision at 10* does not improve for `patience` number of epochs, early stopping is performed.

```
class CustomEarlyStopping(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, patience=0):
        super(CustomEarlyStopping, self).__init__()
        self.patience = patience
        self.best_weights = None
        
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        # The number of epoch it has waited when loss is no longer minimum.
        self.wait = 0
        # The epoch the training stops at.
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        # Initialize the best as infinity.
        self.best_v_loss = np.Inf
        self.best_map10 = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): 
        v_loss=logs.get('val_loss')
        map10=logs.get('val_average_precision_at_k10')

        # If BOTH the validation loss AND map10 does not improve for 'patience' epochs, stop training early.
        if np.less(v_loss, self.best_v_loss) and np.greater(map10, self.best_map10):
            self.best_v_loss = v_loss
            self.best_map10 = map10
            self.wait = 0
            # Record the best weights if current results is better (less).
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                print("Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.")
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
                
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print("Epoch %05d: early stopping" % (self.stopped_epoch + 1))
```

It is then used as:

```
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    steps_per_epoch=5,
    epochs=30,
    verbose=0,
    callbacks=[CustomEarlyStopping(patience=10)],
)
```

Comment: ops!, you should have waited a bit to use my code ;) gd luck.

Comment: @Ghanem Thanks! I appreciate your effort and expanding of your first answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by by creating a custom callback. Information on how to do that is located [here.](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/) Below is some code that illustrates what you can do in a custom callback. The documentation I referenced shows many other options.

```
class LRA(keras.callbacks.Callback): # subclass the callback class
# create class variables as below. These can be accessed in your code outside the class definition as LRA.my_class_variable, LRA.best_weights
    my_class_variable=something  # a class variable
    best_weights=model.get_weights() # another  class variable
# define an initialization function with parameters you want to feed to the callback
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, etc):
        super(LRA, self).__init__()
        self.param1=param1
        self.param2=param2
        etc for all parameters
        # write any initialization code you need here

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):  # method runs on the end of each epoch
        v_loss=logs.get('val_loss')  # example of getting log data at end of epoch the validation loss for this epoch
        acc=logs.get('accuracy') # another example of getting log data 
        LRA.best_weights=model.get_weights() # example of setting class variable value
        print(f'Hello epoch {epoch} has just ended') # print a message at the end of every epoch
        lr=float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)) # get the current learning rate
        if v_loss > self.param1:
           new_lr=lr * self.param2
           tf.keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, new_lr) # set the learning rate in the optimizer
        # write whatever code you need
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create your own callback.
In the following I added a solution that monitors both the accuracy and the loss. You can replace the acc with your own metric:

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    acc = {}
    loss = {}
    best_weights = None
    
    def __init__(self, patience=None):
        super(CustomCallback, self).__init__()
        self.patience = patience
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        epoch += 1
        self.loss[epoch] = logs['loss']
        self.acc[epoch] = logs['accuracy']
    
        if self.patience and epoch > self.patience:
            # best weight if the current loss is less than epoch-patience loss. Simiarly for acc but when larger
            if self.loss[epoch] < self.loss[epoch-self.patience] and self.acc[epoch] > self.acc[epoch-self.patience]:
                self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
            else:
                # to stop training
                self.model.stop_training = True
                # Load the best weights
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
        else:
            # best weight are the current weights
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
```

Please bear in mind that if you want to control the minimum change in the monitored quantity (aka. min_delta) you have to integrate it in the code.

Here is the documentation for how to build your custome callback: [custom_callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback)

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. It's just boilerplate code from the documentation. It doesn't do what OP wants...

Comment: I believe in the documentation I reference there is an example of using a custom callback for early stopping

Comment: @NicolasGervais, the solution is added.

Comment: rather than just doing early stopping I recommend modifying your custom callback to adjust the learning rate based on validation loss and the mean average precision at 10. This may afford the opportunity to get higher model performance . Should be easy to implement within your callback.

Comment: Thanks @GerryP, you're right. This is the basic code, many things could be added above ;)

Answer (score 0):

At this point it would be more simple to make a custom loop and just use if-statements. E.g.:

```
def main(epochs=50):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        fit(epoch)

        if test_acc.result() > .8 and topk_acc.result() > .9:
            print(f'\nEarly stopping. Test acc is above 80% and TopK acc is above 90%.')
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(epochs=100)
```

Here's a simple custom training loop using this method:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

data, info = tfds.load('iris', split='train',
                       as_supervised=True,
                       shuffle_files=True,
                       with_info=True)

def preprocessing(inputs, targets):
    scaled = tf.divide(inputs, tf.reduce_max(inputs, axis=0))
    return scaled, targets

dataset = data.filter(lambda x, y: tf.less_equal(y, 2)).\
    map(preprocessing).\
    shuffle(info.splits['train'].num_examples)

train_dataset = dataset.take(120).batch(4)
test_dataset = dataset.skip(120).take(30).batch(4)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(info.features['label'].num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])


loss_object = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
test_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()

train_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
test_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

topk_acc = tf.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=2)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)


@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_object(labels, logits)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    train_loss(loss)
    train_acc(labels, logits)


@tf.function
def test_step(inputs, labels):
    logits = model(inputs)
    loss = loss_object(labels, logits)

    test_loss.update_state(loss)
    test_acc.update_state(labels, logits)

    topk_acc.update_state(labels, logits)

def fit(epoch):
    template = 'Epoch {:>2} Train Loss {:.3f} Test Loss {:.3f} ' \
               'Train Acc {:.2f} Test Acc {:.2f} Test TopK Acc {:.2f} '

    train_loss.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()

    topk_acc.reset_states()

    for X_train, y_train in train_dataset:
        train_step(X_train, y_train)

    for X_test, y_test in test_dataset:
        test_step(X_test, y_test)

    print(template.format(
        epoch + 1,
        train_loss.result(),
        test_loss.result(),
        train_acc.result(),
        test_acc.result(),
        topk_acc.result()
    ))


def main(epochs=50):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        fit(epoch)

        if test_acc.result() > .8 and topk_acc.result() > .9:
            print(f'\nEarly stopping. Test acc is above 80% and TopK acc is above 90%.')
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(epochs=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code after correction on above answer

```html
class CustomEarlyStopping(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, patience=0):
        super(CustomEarlyStopping, self).__init__()
        self.patience = patience
        self.best_weights = None
        
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        # The number of epoch it has waited when loss is no longer minimum.
        self.wait = 0
        # The epoch the training stops at.
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        # Initialize the best as infinity.
        self.best_val_loss = np.Inf
        self.best_binary_accuracy = 0
        self.best_precision = 0
        self.best_recall = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): 
        val_loss=logs.get('val_loss')
        val_binary_accuracy=logs.get('val_binary_accuracy')
        val_precision=logs.get('val_precision')
        val_recall=logs.get('val_recall')

        # If BOTH the validation loss AND map10 does not improve for 'patience' epochs, stop training early.
        if np.less(val_loss, self.best_val_loss) or np.greater(val_binary_accuracy, self.best_binary_accuracy) or np.greater(val_precision, self.best_precision) or np.greater(val_recall, self.best_recall):
            if self.best_val_loss > val_loss:
                self.best_val_loss = val_loss
            if self.best_binary_accuracy < val_binary_accuracy:
                self.best_binary_accuracy = val_binary_accuracy
            if self.best_precision < val_precision:
                self.best_precision = val_precision
            if self.best_recall < val_recall:
                self.best_recall = val_recall
            self.wait = 0
            # Record the best weights if current results is better (less).
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                print("Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.")
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
                
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print("Epoch %05d: early stopping" % (self.stopped_epoch + 1))
```